# JavaScript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript

This is a stupid question, but I've read over the code 10 times and can't find an "unexpected" ( anywhere. Maybe I'm just tired. Am I doing something else wrong?

```
function(){
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
  var lists = {
    todo: document.getElementById('todo')
    done: document.getElementById('done')
  };

  var makeTaskHtml = function(str) {
    var el = document.createElement('li');
    el.textContent = str; 

    return el; 
  };

  var addTask = function(list, task) {
    list.appendChild(task);
  };

  addTask(list.todo, makeTaskHtml('test task to-do'));
  addTask(list.done, makeTaskHtml('test task done'));
};
```

Comment: Missing  comma between your items in `list`. Also should have a semi-colon at the end of the line where `btn` is defined.

Comment: @TiesonT. That's correct, but the comma is the problem. The semi-colon doesn't matter either way.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I side with the Bobs on this one: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-semicolons

Comment: @TiesonT. I'm not trying to imply that as a practice, just in terms of the functional problem here.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, the comma was not the error that this question was asking about because the interpreter didn't even make it there - https://jsfiddle.net/4sebgx3w/ - The comma would be a subsequent error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` - https://jsfiddle.net/nhayt88e/

Answer (score 2):

Your `lists` variable object properties were not separated with a comma.

Before:

```
var lists = {
  todo: document.getElementById('todo')
  done: document.getElementById('done')
};
```

After:

```
var lists = {
  todo: document.getElementById('todo'),
  done: document.getElementById('done')
};
```

I assume you just left this off the code you posted, but you can not just have `function(){}` at the beginning. You need to have `foo = function(){}` or `function foo(){}`.

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected `(` is because you didn't name your function. There's also missing semi colon (after `btn` declaration) and comma (in `list` obj declaration, after `todo`)

```
function derp(){
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  var lists = {
    todo: document.getElementById('todo'),
    done: document.getElementById('done')
  };

  var makeTaskHtml = function(str) {
    var el = document.createElement('li');
    el.textContent = str; 

    return el; 
  };

  var addTask = function(list, task) {
    list.appendChild(task);
  };

  addTask(list.todo, makeTaskHtml('test task to-do'));
  addTask(list.done, makeTaskHtml('test task done'));
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joa2osvp/

Comment: Semicolons are optional in Javascript and will not throw an error. They are however bad practice and should be added.

Comment: Naming a function is optional and will not throw this error. However, in this context, the function is useless if you don't assign it to anything. The real problem for the error is as stated above in the comments, the missing comma

Comment: @jakekimds You either have to name a function or assign it to a variable. Simply declaring a function without a name will yield the error (See https://jsfiddle.net/4sebgx3w/). Furthermore, there was no unexpected `(` from the missing `,`.

Comment: @DaveLasley I could never make my browser give me an error with the code so I assumed that's what it was (stupid outdated browser). Now I'm just embarrassed.